# Magento 2: create a coupon code using events and observers

Tags: event-observer, magento2.2, coupon

I need to create a coupon code for different customers based on their country.

For example: If the customer is from **US**, the discount should be **10%** and if it is **UK**, it should be **20%**. This I have to create using events and observers. How can I do this?

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: I have created 2 events CouponUS & CouponUK and its corresponding observer. In the controller, I have etched the customer address and dispatched the event according to the country. Now I have to get some idea how will I trigger this event when customer clicks on the coupon code

Comment: How are you tracking customer location? As per shipping address? or from IP?

Comment: As per Shipping Address